# Hide and Show Div content inside of a JQuery dialog

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a single field inside of a Div with a label and its validation summary. It's part a modal JQuery dialog:

```
<table>
.
.
.
<div id="user-date-add">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="100">
                            <div class="editor-label">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Date)
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="editor-field">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.Date)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.Date)
                            </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </div>
.
.
.
```

Depending on a certain condition inside of the JavaScript function I need to hide or show this section with the Date field and related data inside of that Div

So I tried:

```
   if(condition)
    {
     $("#user-date-add").hide();
    }
     else
    {
      $("#user-date-add").show();
    }
```

I also tried to utilize:

```
$("#user-date-add").trigger();
```

It doesn't work. The field on the form doesn't even blink. Is it because the div is rendered inside of the modal popup ? Or is it because there are input tags inside ?
By the way the Editor Date field appears as DatePicker.

How can I make this work ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your sample appears incomplete. If this div is inside a modal dialog, where's the modal dialog declared? When are you trying to hide `#user-date-add`? Is it before or after the dialog is displayed?

Comment: Is the 'condition' you have in the if statement a click(), have you tried using live()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently having DIV tags inside of the table cells is not valid.

I removed the divs and added the ID to the actual row that I need to .Hide() / .Show().

```
                <tr id="user-date-add">
                    <td width="100">
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User.Date)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User.Date)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User.Date)
                        </div>
                    </td>

                </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Say the dialog has an ID of `dialog-box`, then you could try using
`$('#dialog-box #user-date-add').hide();` It may be because of the way the dialog is instantiating and may be leaving the existing div there which means your jQuery selector isn't working properly.

Try using Firebug in Firefox or the Web Inspector in Chrome to try different variations of things like the following in the Console.

```
$('#user-date-add');
$('[id=user-date-add]');
$('[id=user-date-add');
$('.editor-label');
```

Hope it helps,
Dave

Comment: Hmmm FireBUg shows my div outside out the table just as 
<div id="user-date-add"></div>

Seems like It simply doesn't like Divs inside of a table...hmmm

Comment: I had to get rid of the <div> and hide/show the actual row. Thanks David. Firebug helped.